# How to get User current location using beacons for the indoors api?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I have integrate the indoors API in my Project. and also followed all the steps to generate map for indoor location using fingerprint technique(using Mobile tool kit). But I am not getting the exact location of current User.
whenever I moved from one position to another position. The marker goes to nearest Beacons. But it is not moving when user is slowly moving in the area.
Please give me suggestion what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: iBeacons don't give particularly accurate indoor location - They only give an approximate distance to the beacon and this is non-directional, so it effectively gives a circular region.

Comment: Can there be any trilateration methods to find the user location?

Comment: Trilateration is difficult - you don't have any angles/direction as iBeacon is non-directional.  You can try and use the RSSI to calculate the intersection of the circular regions but the signal strength is affected by the orientation of the device, the way the person is holding it and so on.

Comment: Iam also facing same issue with Indoors API, did u get any solution for this ?? 
Could you please suggest me ??

Thanks